# Recursion and Variables in Javascript - Difference with Python

Tags: javascript, python, recursion

I have a uncyclic directed graph, represented by a dictionnary (example `{1: [2,3] , 2:[], 3: [4], 4:[]}` ).

I want to find the size of the longest branch from a given source vertex, let say 1 for this example.

I wrote following javascript recursive function:

```js
function computeLongest(graph, node){
    if (graph[node].length === 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        var l = [];
        for (var i=0; i < graph[node].length; i++){
            l.push(computeLongest(graph, graph[node][i]));
        }
        return 1+Math.max(l);
    }
        
}
```

If I test this function with previous example, simple tree which looks like :

```
  1
 / \
2   3
     \
      4
```

My result is 2 and not 3. It looks like my list `l` is beeing modified in the recursive calls of the function.

If I write the same function in Python, it works fine.

Are there any differences between Python and Javascript in the way we handle recursion and associated variables ? I don't understand why the behaviour is not the same.

Python code:

```
def c(graph, number):
    if len(graph[number]) == 0:
        return 1
    l = []
    for child in graph[number]:
        l.append(c(graph, child))
    return 1+max(l)
```

Comment: Can you try `return 1+Math.max(...l);`?

Comment: Even when working in a dynamic language it can be a useful discipline to think in terms of *types*, you would likely have caught the error. Not sure why this is drawing the DVs though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is probably from a difference in `max` implementation.

The `max` function in python doesn't behave like `Math.max` in javascript. If given an array, Python will find a way to get the maximum value out of it. Javascript will not. In javascript, the expected input is a list of arguments, e.g `Math.max(1,4,3,2)`.

Ex:

**Python**

```
max([1,4,3,2]) # returns 4
```

**Javascript**

```
Math.max([1,4,3,2]) # returns NaN
```

In fact, I am surprised that your javascript code works.

---

*Update*

As stated in the comments, you may use the spread operator `...` to use `Math.max` with an array and still, provide the expected input.

`Math.max(...[1,4,3,2])` is equivalent to `Math.max(1,4,3,2)`, hence `Math.max(...l)` will expand in `Math.max(l[0], l[1]... l[N])`.

Comment: Well his code should work with `Math.max(...[1,4,3,2])`;

Comment: @null Yes, it should work. I wanted to answer his question about "why" he was getting the issue.